# Select SQL query FROM table, select using that query?

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm trying to do the following in SQL alone. In the end it will end up on a wso2 DSS server but if it can be done in sql alone even better :)

Sudocode

```
Array results=Array;
result = <sql>select id, query from definitions</sql>
foreach result.query
    r=<sql>query</sql>
        results.push(r)
```

I am trying to run a select on table a that returns 2 columns.
One of the two columns is named query, and I want to then execute that query returning
id, query_title, query_text

We can assume that the query column always returns the same columns (through aliases written in the query)

The other option would be doing this in WSO2 DSS however I though at least that it can only do what sql does. Maybe joining with the ESB I could get it if that doesn't work but really my goal would be to do it ALL in sql as I am going to insert insert information and then update it into another table anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with a single `select` query.

One solution is to do this in two steps.  Fetch the query in the application using your SQL and then execute the second query from the application.

The second solution is to use a stored procedure and `prepare`/`execute`.  How you then fetch the results depends on the nature of the results